# Using an F# library in a C# project in Xamarin

Tags: c#, f#, xamarin

I have a solution in Xamarin Studio with a C# console program trying to call an F# library.

The reference is fine, everything builds.

My F# code looks like the following:

```
namespace MyStore.Library

module public Lookup =

    open System

    let lookup name (age:int) =
        String.Format("{0}, {1}", name, age.ToString() );
```

I can call the F# library from an F# console and a C# library from the C# console, but I can't *mix* the two.

The C# console doesn't see any F# namespaces at all.

What am I doing wrong?

What should I do to see the F# namespace from C#?

Comment: Post how you're trying to call `lookup` from your C# program. There's nothing obviously wrong here (minus the unnecessary `;` at the end).

Comment: Are you sure you are building both against the same version of the framework?

Comment: where can we get some of these 'crazy pills'?

Comment: it should work without even noticing.. did you find what was wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

In the C# project, you need to add a reference to your F# project.

In the Solution pane, expand your project, and click the gear icon -> Edit References

Then go to Projects tab, check the F# project you want to reference to, then click OK.

[image: edit references]
[image: projects]

Also, make sure both C# and F# project target to the same .NET framework! To check that, right click a project, Options -> Build -> General

[image: right click projects]
[image: target]